# How can I refresh or disable source tracking in particular sandbox or scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-error, sf, source-tracking

I know that I could set source tracking to disabled when I create a sandbox or scratch org, but if I already have created sandbox or scratch org created with source tracking enabled and now I have some strange errors when I try to push or pull metadata. How can I get rid of these errors?

In the past, I was just deleting `.sfdx/orgs` folder with a

`rm -rf .sf/orgs` or `rm -rf .sfdx/orgs` command.

However, now when I try to execute this command, that doesn't help.

How can I resolve those strange errors?

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of executing `rm -rf .sf/orgs` or `rm -rf .sfdx/orgs` command, we could just execute `sf project delete tracking -p` command, which would just delete local tracking files, which means everything should be deployed now, but it doesn't help me.

Another `sf project reset tracking -p` command would set local files to match the remote source tracking. So there would be no changes to deploy, but this doesn't help me either.

Actually what I need to do, is to reset remote tracking, for which we could use the following script:

```
for OUTPUT in $(sf data query -q 'select id from SourceMember' -t --json | jq '.result.records[].Id' -r)
do
    sf data delete record -t -s 'SourceMember' -i $OUTPUT
done
```

Comment: If you are answering your own question, may I suggest adding the "what I tried already, but doesn't work" to your original question instead?

Comment: yes, I added that - I tried to execute rm -rf .sf/orgs

Comment: I meant adding them to the original/question post (the part where you describe the issue and what didn't work), not to the answer post.

Comment: yes, so they are in the question post